# line div's up in a colum with 2 on either side of the column

Tags: html, css, multiple-columns

I'm trying to get a column of divs to line up like this image where there are 2 separate divs lined up to the left or right of the column (item to right is associated with item 5 in the column and item to the left is associated with item 6)

is there a way to do this with css?

[image]
here is what i have:

```
<div id="waterfall">
<div class="fall" id="water1">Defaulter’s Initial Margin</div>
<div class="fall" id="water2">Defaulter’s Guaranty Fund Contribution</div>
<div class="fall" id="water3">Clearing House Contribution $20 Million</div>
<div class="fall" id="water4">Guaranty Fund<br>Total Value XX Million</div>
<div class="fall" id="water5">Unfunded contributions - assessment</div>
<div class="fall" id="water6">Service Continuity Phase</div>
<div class="fall" id="water7">Service Closure</div>
</div>
```

and my css is this:

```
.fall {
overflow:hidden;
margin: 0 auto 10px;
color:white;
text-align:center;
width: 33%;
padding: 10px;
text-transform:uppercase;

}
#water2:after {
    border-top: 80px solid #0099CC;
    border-left: 60px solid transparent; 
    border-right: 60px solid transparent; 
    bottom: 0px;
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: 45%;
    margin-left: -21px;
    width: 0; 
    height: 0;
}
#water1 {background-color:#686868;}
#water2 {background-color:#797979;}
#water3 {background-color:#828282;}
#water4 {background-color:#8B8B8B;}
#water5 {background-color:#949494;}
#water6 {background-color:#9D9D9D;}
#water7 {background-color:#AFAFAF;}
```

thank you for your assistance.

Answer (score 1):

I added divs inside the fall class div, which will appear left (or right) of the parent div.

I accomplished this using the `position: absolute` and for it to work I added `position: relative` to the parent div: the `div.fall`.

Also I removed the `overflow: hidden` from the `.fall divs`
Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/srup9b59/5/ or [full screen](https://jsfiddle.net/srup9b59/5/embedded/result/)

html:

```
<div id="waterfall">
    <div class="fall" id="water1">Defaulter’s Initial Margin</div>
    <div class="fall" id="water2">Defaulter’s Guaranty Fund Contribution</div>
    <div class="fall" id="water3">Clearing House Contribution $20 Million</div>
    <div class="fall" id="water4">Guaranty Fund
        <br>Total Value XX Million</div>
    <div class="fall" id="water5">Unfunded contributions - assessment
        <div class="test_left">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text</div>
    </div>
    <div class="fall" id="water6">Service Continuity Phase
        <div class="test_right">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text</div>
    </div>
    <div class="fall" id="water7">Service Closure</div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.fall {
    margin: 0 auto 10px;
    color:white;
    text-align:center;
    width: 33%;
    padding: 10px;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    color: red;
    position: relative;
}
#water2:after {
    border-top: 80px solid #0099CC;
    border-left: 60px solid transparent;
    border-right: 60px solid transparent;
    bottom: 0px;
    content:"";
    position: absolute;
    left: 45%;
    margin-left: -21px;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
}
.test_left {
    border: 1px solid black;
    color: black;
    height: auto;
    left: -260px;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: left;
    width: 300px;
}
.test_right {
    border: 1px solid black;
    color: black;
    height: auto;
    right: -260px;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: left;
    width: 300px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This would be relatively simple to achieve if the popout boxes of additional info were aligned to the top of its adjacent `<div>` rather than vertically centered. To do so, I would put the `<div class="popout>` inside the `.fall` element. Make sure `.fall` is set to `position: relative;` and you can position the additional content easily.

A simple JS Fiddle to explain: https://jsfiddle.net/L0s28c6s/

Vertical centering is a difficult thing to do, espcially here where you need the additional content (the `.popout` elements) to not disrupt the flow of the `.fall` elements.

A less elegant solution would be to use JS to position the popout elements. Get the co-ordinates of the `.fall` item and subtract half of its height to find its vertical center. Then get the height of the `.popout`, halve it and then subtract this from the yPos mentioned earlier... **I don't recommend this solution though** – using JS for layouts like this is fraught with inefficiency and overhead on the user.

Answer (score 1):

**HTML**

```
<div id="waterfall">
   <div class="fall" id="water1">Defaulter’s Initial Margin</div>
   <div class="fall" id="water2">Defaulter’s Guaranty Fund Contribution</div>
   <div class="fall" id="water3">Clearing House Contribution $20 Million</div>
   <div class="fall" id="water4">Guaranty Fund<br>Total Value XX Million</div>
   <div class="fall" id="water5">Unfunded contributions - assessment
       <div class="text-box" id="text-box-2">text text text text text text text 
                text text text text text text text text text text text text</div>
   </div>
   <div class="fall" id="water6">Service Continuity Phase
       <div class="text-box" id="text-box-1">text text text text text text 
                text text text text text text text text text text text text text</div>
   </div>
   <div class="fall" id="water7">Service Closure</div>
</div><!-- end #waterfall -->
```

Notes:

- side divs are nested in associated `.fall` divs

**CSS**

```
html, body { height: 100%; }

#waterfall { 
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

.fall {
    overflow: visible;
    margin: 0 auto 10px;
    color:white;
    text-align:center;
    width: 33%;
    padding: 10px;
    text-transform:uppercase;

}
#waterfall:after {
    border-top: 80px solid #0099CC;
    border-left: 60px solid transparent; 
    border-right: 60px solid transparent; 
    bottom: 0;
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, 0);
    width: 0; 
    height: 0;
}
#water1 {background-color:#686868;}
#water2 {background-color:#797979;}
#water3 {background-color:#828282;}
#water4 {background-color:#8B8B8B;}
#water5 {background-color:#949494; position: relative;}
#water6 {background-color:#9D9D9D; position: relative;}
#water7 {background-color:#AFAFAF;}

.text-box {
    height: 75px;
    width: 125px;
    font-size: .7em;
    text-align: left;
    color: black;
    padding: 2px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    background-color: #eee;
}

#text-box-1 {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -20px;
    left: -175px;
}

#text-box-1::after {
    content: "\2192";
    font-size: 3em;
    color: #ccc;
    position: absolute;
    left: 123px;
    top: 11px;
}

#text-box-2 {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -20px;
    right: -170px;
}

#text-box-2::before {
    content: "\2190";
    font-size: 3em;
    color: #ccc;
    position: absolute;
    left: -29px;
    top: 10px;
}
```

Notes:

- `.fall` container divs (`#water5` & `#water6`) given `position: relative` to establish them as nearest positioned ancestor for absolute positioning
- Side divs (`#text-box-1` & `#text-box-2`) positioned absolutely relative to container divs
- Arrows (pseudo-elements) positioned absolutely relative to side divs
- [CSS encoding](http://brajeshwar.github.io/entities/) used for arrows
- `overflow: hidden` in `.fall` changed to `overflow: visible` so side divs have visibility
- With regard to the blue down arrow, I applied precise horizontal centering. I also positioned it to the bottom of the container (`#waterfall`). It had been positioned relative to `.fall` div `#water2`. It will still overlap content on vertical re-sizing of the screen, but that may be what you want. I didn't spend much time on this item because I don't know how important it is to the layout and it wasn't part of the question.

---

The code above renders this:

[image]

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/wxzrn6sc/1/

Comment: Thank you!  clear and concise.  I admin the blue arrow wasn't supposed to be there, i'm trying to get it to be smaller and in-between each of the divs.  Any idea there?

Comment: You can make the blue arrow smaller by adjusting the border properties in `#waterfall:after`. You can position the arrows between divs using the same CSS method used to position the side divs: absolute positioning relative to the associated container div. Chrome dev tools is great for testing these sorts of things.

Comment: I'm not sure why it's not working...
I changed it to this:
.fall:after {
    border-top: 8px solid #0099CC;
    border-left: 6px solid transparent; 
    border-right: 6px solid transparent; 
    bottom: 0;
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, 0);
}
but it doesn't display properly.

Comment: Your code didn't work because you didn't specify `position: relative` on the `.fall` element. http://jsfiddle.net/wxzrn6sc/2/

Comment: @rudtek, I noticed you unaccepted my answer. If there's anything I can do to earn it back let me know. I'm not sure what the problem is, but I'm happy to work with you until the issue is resolved.